# Revoked certificate causes browser alerts to not trust website when accessed via SSL

Tags: https

I revoked the certificate for my website and now every time I navigate to its SSL version, e.g. https://example.com, I get an alert from all browsers that the site should not be trusted.

How can resolve this issue when someone tries to open the site from HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

That is what revoking a certificate is supposed to do: use of the certificate can no longer be trusted.

You will need to obtain a new SSL certificate and install it on your server so that your visitors can see your HTTPS site again without receiving an alert.

Comment: I don't need anymore the certificate for many reasons. It's not a way to revoke the certificate and not have the alert from all browsers that the site should not be trusted?

Comment: The only way to not get that alert for a revoked certificate would be to stop using the certificate.

Comment: So it's better to revoke the certificate or wait until expired and not renew it? If expired then the alerts will be stop or not?